# Can't find RemoteSpringApplication on Intellij for live reload on Docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to run a Docker SpringBoot Project with live reload using SpringBoot Devtools and following [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

I made the changes in my `POM.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>br.com.myproject.teste</groupId>
   <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>hello</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>build</scope>
         <optional>false</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

And added the secret configuration on my `application.properties`

```
spring.devtools.remote.secret=${SPRING_REMOTE_SECRET:secret}
```

When I try to create de Intellij configurarion to use the `RemoteSpringApplication` as main class
it cannot find the class, in fact it does not find the `org.springframework.boot.devtools` whole package.

The application is running in Docker container created from this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/hello-ms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "/app/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And except for the live reload functionality, it is working. Am I missing something?

Edit 1: There was a problem with the scope of the devtools plugin. (thanks @xerx593)

Edit 2: THe live reload and devtools seems to be working fine and if I run the application locally with `mvn spring-boot:run`, it reloads when changes are made in the project. The problem is running the project via `SpringRemoteApplication` that IntelliJ can't find so I can configure it as main class

Comment: (1.) `build` is no valid scope in maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: 2. "Note Developer tools are automatically disabled ... You can control this behavior by using the `spring.devtools.restart.enabled` system property. To enable devtools, irrespective of the classloader used to launch your application, set the `-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=true` system property. **This must not be done in a production environment where running devtools is a security risk.** To disable ..."

Comment: from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools:

Comment: 3. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.remote-applications

Comment: I've fixed the scope and added the `spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true` on my `application.properties` but still nothing. the devtool package is not in the "External Libraries" in IntelliJ either